# calculate number of observation with a specific status in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

Consider df below. 
[image]

I want to know on a given day in 2000, how many observations have status T.
(creating the full out put table is not doable (365days!))
but something like below.

```
dates = c("12/27/1999", "02/14/2000",
  "01/07/2000", "01/09/2000", "02/04/2000", "09/04/2000", "01/08/2001",
  "10/01/1998", "04/05/2000", "02/09/2001")

status = c("T", "F", 
           "T", "F", "T", "F", "T",
           "F", "T", "F")


df <- data.frame(letter = c(rep("a", 2), 
                            rep("b", 5),
                            rep("c", 3)),
                 status_code = c(12,3,15,45,16,3,35,24,19,22),
                 date = as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%y"),
                 status = status)
```

I am not sure where to begin. I would appreciate any hint to help me with this.

Comment: Do you want `df %>% group_by(year = format(date, "%Y")) %>% summarise(Count = sum(status == "T"))`

Comment: @akrun, actually no. I want to count number of observations with T status, for each day in 2000. ie. 01/01/2000 (0), 01/02/2000 (0), ... 01/07/2000 (1) and so on up to 12/31/2000

Comment: Do you have duplicates for the 'date' column, then do a `group_by(date)`

Comment: Sorry, your expected is not clear

Comment: @akrun sorry about that. so for example a enters year 2000 with status T and holds its status from Jan1 to Feb 14. and b holds its T status from Jan7 to 9 and then from feb 4 to sep 4 ,. so on Jan 1 we have only one observation with status T,... on Jan 7 we have two...I did my best to create an output to visualize this but it seems not doable as a small example or I do not know how to.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, I think this helps you:

```
df %>% 
mutate(status1 =  as.factor(status)) %>% 
group_by(date, status1) %>%
select(date, status1) %>% count()
```

I repeated a fact

#### output:

```
date       status1     n
2019-10-01 F           1
2019-12-27 T           1
2020-01-07 T           1
2020-01-08 T           1
2020-01-09 F           1
2020-02-04 T           1
2020-02-09 F           1
2020-02-14 F           1
2020-04-05 T           2 # here
2020-09-04 F           1
```